# Compare $\mathbb{E}[XY]\mathbb{E}[XY]$ with $\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[XY^2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$So this was a question asked to me in an interview where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables and I was asked to compare the $\E[XY]\E[XY]$ with $\E[X]\E[XY^2]$ . The interviewer didn't give any more details. I am not exactly sure what he wanted.

Comment: For one thing, $\operatorname{E}(XY) \operatorname{E}(XY)$ cannot be negative (assuming $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued) whereas $\operatorname{E}(X) \operatorname{E}(XY^2)$ could be negative. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, but I am pretty sure he wanted something more.

Comment: I had given this answer, he wasn't impressed and all he said was what if they are not.

Comment: Your subject line says $\operatorname{E}(Y)\operatorname{E}(XY^2)$ but your question says $\operatorname{E}(X)\operatorname{E}(XY^2)$. $\qquad$

Comment: Approved the edit.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No if X and Y are independent, they are not equal, because $E(Y^2)$ is not always equal to $E(Y)^2$

Comment: Nice catch Xoff. Now I know why he didn't seem impressed in interview. Damn!

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}} \newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{cov}} \newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$
Let's look at their conditional distributions given $X$:
\begin{align}
& \E(X\mid X)\E(XY^2\mid X) - \E(XY\mid X)\E(XY\mid X) \\
= {} & X^2 \Big( \E(Y^2\mid X) - \left( \E(Y\mid X) \right)^2 \Big) \\
= {} & X^2 \Big( \var(Y\mid X) \Big) \ge 0.
\end{align}
Hence with probability $1$, we have
$$
\E(X\mid X)\E(XY^2\mid X) \ge \E(XY\mid X)\E(XY\mid X).
$$
More later, maybe$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: This looks good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something can be said if $X\ge 0$: By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
\left(\Bbb E[XY]\right)^2=\left(\Bbb E[\sqrt{X}\cdot\sqrt{X}Y]\right)^2\le\Bbb E[X]\cdot\Bbb E[XY^2].
$$

Comment: Can you please explain how to use Cauchy-Schwarz here? I search quite a lot but did not get any article on how does Cauchy-Schwarz translates to this in probability?

Comment: For two square-integrable random variables $A$ and $B$, $(\Bbb E[AB])^2\le\Bbb E[A^2]\cdot \Bbb E[B^2]$. This is one form of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  In your situation take $A = \sqrt{X}$ and $B=\sqrt{X}\cdot Y$, which is okay because $X\ge 0$.

Comment: can you help me prove this form of Cauchy-Schwarz? Or how to covert the standard vectorial form into this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that much can be said about the relationship between the two quantities in general, other than what Michael Hardy has already said. As the following examples show, it's not true that one of the quantities is always larger than the other:

For instance, if $X$ is a random variable taking the values $\pm 1$, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and $Y=X$, then $\mathbb{E}[XY]\mathbb{E}[XY]=1$ while $\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[XY^2]=0$.

On the other hand, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $\mathbb{E}[Y]=0,\mathbb{E}[X]\neq0$, $Y\neq 0$, then $\mathbb{E}[XY]\mathbb{E}[XY]=0$ while $\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[XY^2]=\mathbb{E}[X]^2\mathbb{E}[Y^2]>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example. Notice first that

$$ (\Bbb{E}(XY))^2 - \Bbb{E}X \Bbb{E}(XY^2) = \operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)^2 - (\Bbb{E}X)^2 \operatorname{Var}(Y) - \Bbb{E}[(X - \Bbb{E}X)(Y - \Bbb{E}Y)^2].$$

Now let $(X, Y)$ be a multivariate Gaussian variable. Then the last term vanishes and we have

$$ (\Bbb{E}(XY))^2 - \Bbb{E}X \Bbb{E}(XY^2) = \operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)^2 - (\Bbb{E}X)^2 \operatorname{Var}(Y). \tag{*}$$

Notice that neither $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)$ nor $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ depends on the $\Bbb{E}X$. Thus we are free to choose $\Bbb{E}X$ without changing other terms, and $\text{(*)}$ can attain any values $ \leq \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)^2$. In particular, it can be both positive and negative.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he was looking for you to give an approximation and solve the problem. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then the expectations become $E[X]^2 E[Y]^2$ and $E[X]^2 E[Y^2]$ comparing the two we see the latter is larger by [Jensen's inequality.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)

Comment: This sounds like something he would have wanted.  Still, can we do something if they are not independent?

Comment: I do not think you can do much without the dependence of y on x in that case. Sorry.

Comment: To be fair at an interview they really should give a counter example and room to learn the result rather than just expecting you to know this offhand. Sounds kinda stressful.

Comment: Yes exactly! My bad luck

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\mathbb E(X)\mathbb E(XY^2)-\mathbb E(XY)^2=V(XY)-coV(X,XY^2) $$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent 
$$\mathbb E(X)\mathbb E(XY^2)-\mathbb E(XY)^2= \mathbb E(X)^2V(Y) $$